# Having Trouble converting a string to bytes

Tags: hex, pymodbus, bitstring

I'm trying to convert a string to a byte, thats what I've done.
I want to send out a Modbusprotocol via serial and put it together in bitstring:

```
tiger = '01' 
read = '03'
ac_val = '0031'
word = '0002'

code = tiger+read+ac_val+word
print(code)
010300310002

#now i want to put thist string in a bitstring with the function:

codeh = bytes.fromhex(code)
codeh = b'\x01\x03\x001\x00\x02 #This is what i got
```

But i was expecting:

```
codeh = b'\x01\x03\x00\x31\x00\x02
```

I have no idea why the output is like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it's showing in the output is the ASCII representation of the byte values.  Hex 31 corresponds to the ascii character '1'.  Try this to see a demonstration:

`bytes.fromhex('415343494921')`

Here's a chart that shows these low values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart

Comment: Yeah, that oviously right, but i was wondering why only two values were affected... if write this to the serial interface the values got interpreted right, so it might be only a print() interpretation.

Comment: @Tec_Ley The other values all correspond to unprintable characters: x00 is 'null', x01 is 'start of heading' etc.  Those values are rarely used so just appear as their hex code.  x31 is '1' which mixed with those codes is confusing.